# HttpClientModule fires two requests and one of them doesn't have the authentication header. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

I'm working with HttpClientModule from angular 4.3 on Ionic 3. My application communicates with a Django server that asks for an authentication header that is being sent by an interceptor. The problem I'm facing is that when I ask HttpClientModule to perform the get request, it sends two requests. One with the authentication header, that is not responded, and other with no authentication header. Can anyone help me? I don't know what I am doing wrong :(

Here's what I see in the Web Inspector:

[First request sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9f2l.png)

[Second request sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAfDq.png)

Here's my Provider:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

    private url = "http://10.0.1.50:8000/";

    constructor(public http: HttpClient, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

    getDisp(){
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get(this.url+'api/Dispositivos').subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                resolve(data);
            }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (err instanceof ErrorEvent){
                    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: 'Algo deu errado :(',
                        subTitle: 'Parece que há algo errado com a sua conexão. Tente novamente',
                        buttons: ['OK']
                    });
                    alert.present();
                } else {
                    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: 'Algo deu errado :(',
                        subTitle: 'Desculpe, parece que nossos servidores estão com problemas. Tente novamente em alguns minutos',
                        buttons: ['OK']
                    });
                    alert.present();
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

}

And here's my interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    public credenciais: any;

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if (localStorage.credenciais != null) {
            this.credenciais = JSON.parse(localStorage.credenciais)
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: 'Token '+this.credenciais.token
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Here's the function I use to call the Provider:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from "../../pages/login/login";
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';

[...]

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: RestProvider) {}

[...]

carregaDisp(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.restProvider.getDisp().then(data => {
            if (data == null) {
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
            } else {
                this.dispositivo = data;
                this.atualizaStatus().then(() => {
                    console.log(data);
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I've Googled everything I could think of. Sorry if it's a beginners mistake, but I can't find it's solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see problem with your RestProvider. **You shouldn't subscribe to the observable like that.** You only subscribe to observable when you want to actually get the response, I mean at the place of usage and not inside wrapper methods. It will cause memory leaks. **You should unsubscribe from the observables as well and your way doesn't allow you to do so.**

**Please use something like this.** This way you will get the advantage of new pipeable operators and get clean declarative code.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

getDisp(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.url + 'api/Dispositivos')
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          this.processError(err);
          return of(err);
        }),
      )
      .toPromise();
  }

  processError(err) {
    if (err instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Algo deu errado :(',
        subTitle:
          'Parece que há algo errado com a sua conexão. Tente novamente',
        buttons: ['OK'],
      });
      alert.present();
    } else {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Algo deu errado :(',
        subTitle:
          'Desculpe, parece que nossos servidores estão com problemas. Tente novamente em alguns minutos',
        buttons: ['OK'],
      });
      alert.present();
    }
  }
```

**Example use case of this method will be:**

```
 async refresh() {
    const response = await this.getDisp();
    console.log('response of the getdisp is : ', response);
  }
```